# Is it possible to save and restore the TensorFlow random state (to make Dropout reproducible)?

Tags: tensorflow

Summary: I want to run a model with Dropout in training mode twice, and get the same output both times.

Detail: I'm training a large model that doesn't fit on my GPU during training.

I want to train the model by splitting it into two pieces, A and B.

A single training step goes as follows:

1. Apply A to the inputs in training mode, but without storing intermediate tensors.
2. Compute the gradients for B with respect to weights and to the outputs of A.
3. Apply A to the inputs one more time, this time storing intermediate tensors, then use the gradients from (2) to compute the gradients w.r.t. A's weights.
4. Optimize.

This process works fine on a fully deterministic model.
The problem is that the model uses Dropout extensively. Since Dropout is random, I need the output of A to be the same both times.

So what I would like to do is save the random state before (1), and restore it before (3).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.random.set_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed) to make random operations deterministic. You can also pass a seed to the Dropout layer (or dropout function) to ensure that the results are similar.

If we take an example from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed):

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
```

Both `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` and `tf.nn.dropout` support the seed keyword argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I'm using keras's train_step(), and I would need to change the seed twice during every training step. Do you know how a change in seed can be embedded in the computational graph?